# TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'task' while running timm example code

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying the code below
https://gist.github.com/Chris-hughes10/f5ff0b9100990a72dd62f29b2d93a803#file-train-py

I change the data_dir as the description below for my local dataset

```
data_dir = r"C:\Users\walte\Desktop\dataset\0111"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(data_dir)
```

and the error message shown

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\walte\Desktop\timm\coAt_classifier_v2.ipynb Cell 9 in <cell line: 1>()
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
----> 2     main(data_dir)

c:\Users\walte\Desktop\timm\coAt_classifier_v2.ipynb Cell 9 in main(data_path)
     46 validate_loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
     48 # print(optimizer)
     49 # print(train_loss_fn)
     50 # print(validate_loss_fn,)
     51 # print(mixup_args)
     52 
     53 # Create trainer and start training
---> 54 trainer = TimmMixupTrainer(
     55     model=model,
     56     optimizer=optimizer,
     57     loss_func=train_loss_fn,
     58     eval_loss_fn=validate_loss_fn,
     59     num_classes=num_classes,
     60     callbacks=[
     61         *DEFAULT_CALLBACKS,
     62         SaveBestModelCallback(watch_metric="accuracy", greater_is_better=True),
     63     ],
     64 )
...
----> 7 self.accuracy = torchmetrics.Accuracy(num_classes=num_classes)
      8 self.ema_accuracy = torchmetrics.Accuracy(num_classes=num_classes)
      9 self.ema_model = None

TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'task'
```

How can I fix this?

I have found that the error occurs in the TimmMixupTrainer class, but still don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

new code:

```
from torchmetrics import Accuracy
     torchmetrics_accuracy = Accuracy(task='multiclass',                                           
                                     num_classes=num_classes).to(device)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your task, you need to assign `task` value to the `Accuracy`, e.g. `task: ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multilabel']`. See: https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/accuracy.html#module-interface